# Playing video in angular

Tags: html, angular, angular6, angular7, angular8

I am working on a angular application and I am using video tag of html 5 in my code
to play video. Code is as follows::

```
 <video autoplay>
          <source src="videos/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

In this I just want my video to play once and on completion of video I want to route to next component. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put on your video tag `(ended)="onEnd()"`

Then in `onEnd` inside your component function you just do the router navigation

Comment: how can I call this video code on click of a button in angular?

Comment: Well, you'll only enable your button on video end... You can create an variable for this control in your component like `videoEnded: boolean` that will be true on this function call `onEnd`, after that you can click your button and go to next route

Comment: I want to show video on click of button and when video ends I need to route at other component

Comment: You can use `*ngIf` with a variable like `showVideo`, when you click on your button `showVideo` will be true, after that your video is shown, then just make sure in your `onEnd()` function you call your router navigate

Comment: but how I can bind it with click of a button? sorry if I asked silly question , I am new to angular

Comment: no problem, so put in your button: `<button (click)="showVideo = true"></button>`
or just call a function like `(click)="showVideo()"` that changes `showVideo` to `true`

Comment: got it . I will try this in sometime. I am stuck at one more part of making a pop-up which I asked just now here , It would be helpful if you can guide on that too  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58581671/making-countdown-pop-up-in-angular

Answer (score -1):

Add an event in video-tag

```
<div *ngIf='condition'>
    <video autoplay (ended)='route()'>
        <source src="videos/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
<button (click)='OnClick()'>Play</button>
```

In controller.ts

```
condition = false;
onClick() {
    this.condition = true;
}
```

In route() do the programmatic route.

Comment: how can I call this video code on click of a button in angular?

Comment: Do you want to show the video on the click of a button?

Comment: yes I want to show video on click of button and when video ends I need to route at other component

Comment: got it . thanks.  I am stuck at one more part of making a pop-up which I asked just now here , It would be helpful if you can guide on that too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58581671/making-countdown-pop-up-in-angular